# How to open a file using a text path

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to write a code in click event of Open button which should Open File Specified in `Textbox`.
Is there any code wich can do this Task?

[image]

Comment: Double click the open button in designer, VS will generate a new method for you. Write whatever you need inside that. Which part you have trouble with? Attaching the event? Opening the file?

Comment: I need the code which can open the file.

Comment: This is not "Give me the code" site. What have you tried? We solve your problems, but we won't do your work.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/File_input/output#C.23

Comment: you mean open an application that view PDF or you want to view pdf inside your winform application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(textBox1.Text)`